# Images disappeared after creating react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

The pictures were in the directory:

`public > img`

Links to the pictures were indicated in the json file which is located in:

`src > data > data.json`

After I created the build, the pictures stopped loading into the components I needed. I tried to change the path to the files but it did not lead to anything. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

**Shop.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Instruments.css';
import Cart from '../components/Cart'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import cart from '../img/cart.png';
import data from "../data/data.json";
import OfferForm from '../components/OfferForm';

function Shop() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(data);
    const [modalActive, modalSetActive] = useState(false);
    const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);
    const [offerDoneActive, setOfferDoneActive] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className='shop'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='shop__main'>
                        <div className='shop__main-products'>
                            {
                                currentData.filter((el) => {
                                    return value.toLowerCase() === '' ? el : el.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                                }).map((el, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Product img={el.img} title={el.title} price={el.price} key={el.id} addToCart={() => setCartList([...cartList, el])}/>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

**Product.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Product.css';

function Product({img, title, price, id, type, addToCart}) {
    return (
                <div className='product' key={id} type={type}>
                    <div className='buy__top'>
                        <div className='product__top-image-background'>
                            <img className='product__top-image' src={img}></img>
                        </div>
                        <h3 className='product__top-title'>{title}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='product__buy'>
                        <h3 className='product__buy-price'>{price} грн</h3>
                        <button className='product__buy-button' onClick={addToCart}>В корзину</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
}

export default Product;
```

**Data.json:**

```
[
    {"id":1,"type":"guitar","title":"Гитара Yamaha", "price":"6500", "img":"/img/guitar-yamaha.jpg"},
    {"id":2,"type":"guitar","title":"Гитара Fender", "price":"7300", "img":"/img/guitar-fender.jpg"},
    {"id":3,"type":"violence","title":"Скрипка Yamaha", "price":"16000", "img":"/img/yamaha-violence.jpg"},
    {"id":4,"type":"violence","title":"Скрипка Cervini", "price":"4200", "img":"/img/violence-cervini.jpg"},
    {"id":5,"type":"saxophone","title":"Саксофон Yamaha", "price":"45000", "img":"img/saxophone-yamaha.jpg"},
    {"id":6,"type":"drums","title":"Барабаны Yamaha", "price":"30000", "img":"img/drums-yamaha.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: Can you please also show how the json file is structured? Ta!

Comment: did you try to give full path, for example ```../../public/img/example.jpg"```.